# Proper Hello World in C

Tags: c

What is the correct Hello World program in C?

Since the first page of [Google results for "c hello world"](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+hello+world) vary greatly and many are old C, I would like the standard version in one place for easy copy and paste.

Comment: Do a lot of hello world programming?

Comment: All versions are correct pretty much! And you can pretty much include the whole C library to make a hello world, without a problem! This is not really a constructive question! Constructive would be the most efficient hello world program in C maybe? Or a version that gives a quick overview of syntax and needs (eg stdio.h inclusion, main return type etc.) A hello world is almost always correct as far as I know!!!

Comment: Any program whose sole function is to print `hello world` on your screen is correct. Already this question has elicited a good deal of polling... voting to close.

Comment: There are some correctness issues raised by the question, for example some of the results in that Google search don't specify the return type of `main` (relying on implicit `int`). But I don't think the question is really phrased to draw those issues out: there's no "the correct" hello world; if the question is "what's wrong with this code?" then it should post and ask about specific code, not refer via Google search to all the code in the world; I doubt that SO is the place to curate a "hello world" for every language, at a rate of one question per language.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I believe this is a standard Hello World program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should be `puts("hello")` or `printf("%s","hello")`

Comment: @JanTuroň is puts standard C or possix?

Comment: @KorayTugay:  `puts()` is in Standard C (all editions).  It is also in POSIX.

Answer (score 86):

Depends how lazy you are: :)

```
#error Hello World
```

Comment: I learned something here.  I am new to C so I was unaware that I can introduce my own errors.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, absolutely correct.

Comment: No up or down vote, because sometimes awesome and terrible are the same.

Comment: But this doesn't compile. Compiling != running.

Comment: I didn't accept this answer because while fun, it is not useful as a starting place for a larger program. That is what I usually use Hello World for.

Comment: I can't compile it. Is there something else to the code? I am not fluent in C nor its flavors.

Comment: This program isn't meant to be compiled. You need the gcc interpreter to run it ;-)
(yes, I know, old question ... I didn't resist the temptation ;-) )

Answer (score 18):

In C99 or C2011, you could use these five lines of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello World!");
}
```

Since C99 (but not C89) allows you to omit the `return 0;` at the end, it returns a deterministic status of 0 (success) to the calling environment.  It doesn't have any unused arguments to the function.  It has the prototype for `puts()` from the header.  The output includes an appropriate line ending.  I think it is kosher and essentially minimal.

Comment: You do not even need the "void" I think.

Comment: @KorayTugay: That depends on the compiler options you use.  I use options that insist on the presence of `void`; if you choose to run with sloppier, more permissive options, you can get away without the `void`.

Comment: More accurately, the use of `void` depends on the standard being used.

Comment: @Qix: would you care to elaborate on your comment that 'the use of `void` depends on the standard being used'?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler IIRC ANSI C _required_ them, but C99 and onward states that you can use an implementation-defined `int main()` prototype and still be valid C. The fact compilers allow an empty argument list is to be considered 'implementation defined'.

Comment: @Qix: I think there is some confusion.  For reasons of backwards compatibility, if nothing else, C89 allows `main()` and `int main()` as valid function definitions for `main()` — as well as `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.  However, the versions with empty parentheses do not provide a prototype for the function; the versions like `int main(void)` do provide a prototype.  AFAIK, that part hasn't changed in C99 or C11.  The `int`-less version is no longer standard, but the rest is as before.  If you don't call `main()` recursively, it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 11):

There is more than one, and while Tor's answer is good, I prefer to always use an argc / argv main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

In the rare, odd event that printf was being checked for failure, you might encounter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

extern int errno;
extern FILE *stdout;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  errno = 0;

  int err = printf("Hello World\n");

  if (err < 0) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  err = fflush(stdout);

  if (err < 0 || errno != 0) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  } else {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

Like any C program, this has been modified far too many times in attempts to make it even less buggy.  Special thanks to R.., dmp, and Scooter who really deserve more credit than I can give.

Comment: Your second version contains multiple bugs. `printf` returns the number of characters written, so your error test is wrong. More subtly, this kind of error-checking with stdio is unreliable. If you want to report errors, you need to `fflush` too.

Comment: I always used argc/argv prototype for main, until I started using all warnings and now I have to use (void) in most cases to avoid being told argc/argv are unused.

Comment: @R.. Thanks for the pointers, I modified printf to only check for error (negative) conditions.  I assumed that if stdio was unreliable, reporting errors via printf was unreliable too 
(and flushing it wouldn't help a bit).  That's why the return code was used.

Comment: Don't return -1, return EXIT_FAILURE.

Comment: @dmp Right.  Too much time on platforms where EXIT_FAILURE and -1 were the same.

Comment: It's not that stdio is unreliable, it's that you have to be careful with how you use it in order to give reliable results. The error from a write may be reported anywhere between the original write call (`printf`) and `fflush`, depending on buffering. If there is a write error, you should definitely see it at some point in that range.

Comment: @R.. Ahh, yes, completely understandable.  Which means the return code will be stored before the flush, rendering it practically useless.  So the only decent error detection would be with errno after a fflush.  Got it.

Comment: I can't believe I rewrote it yet again.

Comment: stdio is not required by C to set `errno`. You need to look at the return values of `printf` and `fflush`, and/or `ferror(stdout)`. For example `if (printf("Hello World\n") < 12 || fflush(stdout)) return EXIT_FAILURE;`

Comment: @R.. stdio isn't there to set `errno`.  It's there to declare `printf` and `fflush`.  By your previous logic, if stdio was interrupted during a write (8 bytes written, 4 delayed by interrupt, those 4 flushed afterwards) your if statement would report the write failed.

Comment: I didn't say stdio.h, I said stdio, meaning the functions in the "stdio" part of the standard library. They are not required (by plain C) to set the value of `errno` when they fail. POSIX, however, does require them to do so.

Comment: @R.. According to The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6, my printf will return a negative number if it fails, so it's covered, POSIX or not.  My exit condition is an OR, not an AND.  Still, in a non-terminal setting, errno might be NO_TERM, so I removed it from the expression, until it plays it's role in checking fflush

Comment: You can't fflush(stdin).  More [here](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html)

Comment: @dmp thank you, stupid blindness and wrong choice of file descriptor while attempting to focus on something else.  Yes, it should be stdout.

Comment: "The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6" **is POSIX**. It is not the C standard. The C standard does require `printf` to return a negative number if it fails to write any bytes, but it does not require `errno` to be set giving the reason. POSIX imposes this latter requirement.

Comment: @R.. Thank you for the clarification.  It checks for negative numbers, and will fail on a negative return from printf even if errno isn't set to anything suspicious.  It always did.

Comment: Note that `extern int errno;` is a mistake in modern systems. The only safe way to declare `errno` is by including `<errno.h>` because it can be any modifiable lvalue, and in a threaded environment, that can mean something like: `extern int *_Errno(void); #define errno (*(_Errno()))` (where the function returns the address of the thread-local copy of `errno`).

Answer (score 10):

Official GNU Hello World can be found here: http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/

> The GNU Hello program produces a familiar, friendly greeting. Yes, this is another implementation of the classic program that prints “Hello, world!” when you run it.
>
> However, unlike the minimal version often seen, GNU Hello processes its argument list to modify its behavior, supports greetings in many languages, and so on. The primary purpose of GNU Hello is to demonstrate how to write other programs that do these things; it serves as a model for GNU coding standards and GNU maintainer practices.
>
> GNU Hello is written in C. For implementations in other programming languages, notably including translation into other languages, please see the GNU Gettext distribution.

Comment: +1 Bahahahaha, that's awesome.  Though I can appreciate the serious purpose it serves as a model + coding standards demo.

Comment: At first I thought it was a joke, then I remembered the full-text GPL, and now I don't think it's a joke.

Answer (score 5):

The "official" one would be the one in the first edition of "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie.

[To wit](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.126.4437%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=H1lOUPU-5JnJAZC2gHA&usg=AFQjCNE0mRrYFIweLQKJL8rfP0u_H6hBpA):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Comment: The version of the C language described in 1st ed. K&R C is no longer "correct", nor is it advisable to use it as a reference.

Comment: @SteveJessop -- Depends on what you consider "correct".  It's certainly historic, in that it is the ORIGINAL "hello world".  Would you tell Renoir one of his paintings wasn't "correct"?

Comment: I would if he'd painted a street map of Paris, and someone asked for a "correct" street map of Paris on MapOverflow, and he gave them his from c. 1860. It would no longer be correct, and it would not be advisable to use it as a reference. Interestingly, Wikipedia mentions an earlier "hello world", also by Kernighan, written in B. That's not "correct C" either, but it's certainly historic.

Comment: @SteveJessop Interesting, as this brings to mind my recent toying with temporal databases.  Hot Licks and you are both correct, except temporally you are only interested in current, while Hot Licks is interested in past views of current knowledge.  For hello world, it comes down to requirements, and the only real requirement on that program is that it display "Hello, world!".  If you meet all the requirements, no matter how badly written the code, is it correct?

Comment: @Edwin: to be honest the requirement isn't even that -- a "hello world" program needn't display that exact text :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop -- But it should be noted that the "correct text" is "hello, world", not "Hello World" or "Hello world!" or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KorayTugay: so that the window it is run in doesn't disappear until after you type a character in it.  This is a problem with using IDEs to develop command line programs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How is it related to IDEs? Terminal windows does not disappear either.

Comment: @KorayTugay: Which IDE do you use, on which platform?  You will find a lot of C code on SO that has `system("pause");` (1,800 questions) or `getch()` (3,400 questions) or `getchar()` at the end so that the program does not exit until the user types some input to let it finish.  (The raw numbers are from searches for 'system pause' and 'getch'; some may not be at the end of their programs.)  I understand that's because the terminal windows on Windows in particular vanish when the command exits.  I ran into similar problems with Eclipse and CDT a few years ago now (on Mac).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am totally lost. Anyway thanks for your response and your time. No big issue anyway I guess..

Comment: Err this is usually for people running .exe's directly from the file explorers on Windows since, if compiled in console mode, a console will usually flash and disappear before you can read any text.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "correct"?

I suppose that this one is the most correct, as it doesn't miss anything:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef HELLO_STRING
#define HELLO_STRING "Hello, world!"
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    puts(HELLO_STRING);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this program is not localized; if you want localization, then use "libintl".

Comment: Good question ... what is correct ? versions with argc,argv,... could generate warnings as they are defined but not used.

Comment: @Kwariz I tried it with gcc -Wall -Wunused, it didn't generate these warnings. Which compiler do you mean?

Comment: +1 for the comma in "Hello, world!". ISTR reading that the first-ever "hello world" program had that, so it's clearly more correct.

Comment: @Pupkov-Zadnij well simply add -Wextra : gcc -Wall -Wextra ; I use gcc v4.7 ; but that was just to highlight that "correct" has no useful meaning (in my mind) when talking about The "hello world" source :)

Comment: @Kwariz Yes, you are right, with -Wextra it would warn about unused parameters. Shame on me ;)

Comment: Yes, some aspects are a matter of choice, so there are several correct programs. I was mostly looking to clarify: 1) Return type is int, right? 2) Should the parameters be void, arg-stuff or nothing? 3) Return 0 or not?

Comment: @TorKlingberg It is desireable that return type is int, but it may be void (on some platforms this may lead to unpredictable return-values of your program). Parameters may be void, but I heared that some standards do not allow it. If you return 0, then shell assumes that your program exited normally, if not, it assumes error, which may be cruxial, i.e, when you call your program in a Makefile.

Comment: `void main` is UB and should never be written except on freestanding implementations where `main` is outside the scope of the standard.

Comment: Please don't use envp.  Many implementations support more than two arguments to main, however, programs that define main with three arguments are not strictly conforming.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}

$ c99 hello.c
$ ./a.out
Hello world!
$
```

Comment: Although there is an implicit return of 0 in this case (guaranteed by C99) please consider doing so explicitly as it is highly idiomatic.

Comment: @dmp There are enough answers with an explicit "return 0".  My intention was to say something different :p

Answer (score -1):

Then there's:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  system("echo Hello World!");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `system()` to print text in C. Please use `printf`, `puts`, `fprintf`, but not a ``system("echo Hello world!");``